# How do I make a call to my DomainService method (with parameters) from my ViewModel?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

On the server I have the following method on domainservice class called MeasurementService

```
public MeasurementPresentationModel GetSingleMeasurementPM(Guid Id)
    {
        var m = this.ObjectContext.Measurments.SingleOrDefault(t => t.ID == Id);
        return new MeasurementPresentationModel()
               {
                   ID = m.ID,
                   Objective = m.Objective.Code,
                   ObjectiveID = m.ObjectiveID,
                   MeasurementList = m.MeasurmentList.Code,
                   MeasurementListID = m.MeasurementListID,
                   Weight = m.Wieght,
                   HasEvaluation = m.HasEvaluation,
                   ValidityEndDate = m.ValidityEndDate,
                   ValidityStartDate = m.ValidityStartDate,
                   DataType = m.DataType
               };
    }
```

On my ViewModel I instanciate domain service MeasurementContext _context and tried to write a load method witch is not working:

```
public MeasurementEditViewModel(MeasurementPresentationModel model):this()
    {          
      _context = new MeasurementContext(); 
        var qry = _context.GetSingleMeasurementPMQuery(model.ID);
        var lo = _context.Load(qry);
        lo.Completed += (sender, e) => 
        {
            SelectedMeasurement = lo.Entities;
        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong and how do i make service calls from ViewModels?

Answer (score 0):

Load method is a query method it should return IQueryable or IEnumerable. Try to change contract of your services method like:

```
public IEnumerable<MeasurementPresentationModel> GetSingleMeasurementPM(Guid Id)
```